# Text will not align to top of div

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I've tried vertical-align, margin-top, top, padding, positioning, and any trick I can think of, but I cannot get my text to the top of my div, under any circumstance.  I've never run into this before, so I feel like I am overlooking something dumb...

The important stuff:

HTML

```
        <div id="login">
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">username</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">password</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">new here? | forgot password?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 #login {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 73px;
    width: 260px;
    left: 620px;
    top: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
div.row20 {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
p.gray1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444444;
}
```

I've stripped from my code all attempts to push the text to the top of those divs, as none of them worked.  However, I did try everything I could find.  I want the "row20" div to function as an alignment for my forms.  If I use br, it tends to make it harder to have the text boxes line up to the text.  For some reason, the p text is showing up about 18px down from the top of the parent div.  Nothing I have done has changed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `p` element overflows the `div` container because it has top and bottom default `margins`, so you should remove it to fit your needs :

```
p.gray1 { margin:0; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at8t9wxu/)

Comment: See... I told you it was something dumb. :-)  I had tried this, but I must have had something that interfered with it that I stripped out when nothing worked.  This worked, as it should have.

Answer (score 1):

You're having height in `row20`, so you're having difficulty with the alignment, use line-height:

```
p.gray1{
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #444444;
   line-height: 20px;/*or something that fits your align*/
   margin: 0;/*remove default margins*/
   padding: 0;
}
```

```css
#login {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 73px;
    width: 260px;
    left: 620px;
    top: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
div.row20 {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
p.gray1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444444;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="login">
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">username</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">password</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row20">
                <p class="gray1">new here? | forgot password?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Using line-height: 20px actually pushed my text all the way below the parent div.  So I used line-height: 0x; which worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how you can fix such as these problems,It better you try use firebug extention in firefox and then try your code also you can change values and see results immediatly hence you will not confuse again.